# File extension when open custom file with Xamarin Android

Tags: android-intent, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to open a custom file in my Xamarin Android App but when I open it I can't get the file extension correctly or even the name of my file. I tried with OneDrive and it works but not with Google Drive or even Downloads App.

This is my AndroidManifest:

```
<application android:allowTaskReparenting="true" ...>
    <activity android:launchMode="singleTask" ...>          
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="content" android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" android:pathPattern=".*\\.pec" />
            <data android:scheme="content" android:mimeType="application/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.pec" />
            <data android:scheme="content" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.pec" />
        </intent-filter>
        ...
    </activity>
</application>
```

I get the Intent in the OnNewIntent method because I'm using the SingleTask as a LaunchMode. So my code is this:

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
   string action = intent.Action;
   string type = intent.Type; 
   AN.Uri fileUri = intent.Data; 
   string filename = fileUri.LastPathSegment; 
}
```

And this is what I get as a fileUri and filename.

- From OneDrive: 
  content://com.microsoft.skydrive.content.external/Drive/ID/1/Item/RID/8E63BB6D425F77DA%217395/Stream/1/Property/kn.pec
- From Google Drive:
  content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3DLU5kldI4Leii_fQEr6niunAH6hjV_WGJrQZDf64TSRRqnyqi
- From Downloads:
  content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/4169

Comment: You mean when you open your file in `Google Drive` or `Downloads App` you cant get the file extension and file name? But it did work when you open a file in `One Drive`?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT yes exactly! How can I get the file name from the Intent if it doesn't even appear in the Uri?

Comment: How did you open these file? Please post your code.

Comment: I cant reproduce your problem, could you please share a basic demo which could reproduce this problem?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT this is how I open the files:
AN.Uri fileUri = intent.Data;
MemoryStream data = new MemoryStream();
using (var input = this.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(fileUri))
{
input.CopyTo(data);
input.Close();
}
But the real problem is that I do not get the real filename of the file

Answer (score 0):

That's how I was able to get file name from downloads and from google drive on android:

```
internal static bool TryGetFileNameFromUri(Android.Net.Uri uri, out string displayName)
{
    var result = false;
    displayName = default;

    var resolver = MainActivity.Instance.ContentResolver;

    if (uri.ToString().StartsWith("content://"))
    {
        Android.Database.ICursor cursor = null;
        try
        {
            cursor = resolver.Query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.MoveToFirst())
            {
                displayName = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DisplayName));
                result = true;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            cursor.Close();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```